# Looking for faster way to iterate over pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe called `df_ratings` with about a million rows and 3 columns.

I want to take the data inside this dataframe, apply a transformation on it, and put it inside a numpy matrix called `ratings_matrix`

I wrote the following code to achieve this:

```
for i in range(df_ratings.shape[0]): #fill matrix with ratings. zero = unrated
    current_user = df_ratings.iloc[i, 0] - 1
    current_movie = rated_movies_dictionary[df_ratings.iloc[i, 1]]
    current_rating = df_ratings.iloc[i, 2]

    ratings_matrix[current_movie, current_user] = current_rating
```

It works, but very slowly. Iterating over every row of the dataframe in a for loop is slow. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Hard to tell without any data. But you can get rid of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cuser = df_ratings.iloc[:, 0].values - 1
cmvie = df_ratings.iloc[:, 1].map(rated_movies_dictionary).values
crate = df_ratings.iloc[:, 2].values
ratings_matrix[cmvie, cuser] = crate
```

---

**Response to comment**

> does the .values add something? – Maarten Fabré

Yes! When doing many things, it is often more performant to use numpy arrays.  Since the final goal is to do a slice assignment, I wanted to get everything into numpy arrays.  As a simple demonstration, I've run `timeit` while slicing with a pandas series and with a numpy array from that series.

```
%timeit np.arange(4)[pd.Series([1, 2, 3])]
%timeit np.arange(4)[pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).values]

111 µs ± 2.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
61.1 µs ± 2.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was much faster. I suppose I should read up more on map.

Comment: does the `.values` add something?

Comment: From what I can see it converts it from Series type to a numpy array type.