# Vectorize nestled loops for pairwise distance calculation

Tags: python, pandas, performance, vectorization, pairwise-distance

How to make the script below more efficient?  This is a follow-up to my previous post [Python nested loop issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77915065/12846804)
It currently takes the best part of two hours to process input tables consisting in about 15000 and 1500 rows. Manually processing my data in Excel takes me an order of magnitude less time - not ideal!

I understand that `iterrows` is a bad approach to the problem, and that vectorisation is the way forward, but I am a bit dumbfounded at how it would work in regards to the second for loop.

The following script extract takes two dataframes,

- `qinsy_file_2`
- `segy_vlookup` (ignore the naming on that one).

For every row in the `qinsy_file_2`, it iterates through `segy_vlookup` to calculate distances between coordinates in each file. If this distance is less than a pre-given value (here named `buffer`), it will get transcribed to a new dataframe `out_df`(otherwise it will pass over the row).

```
# Loop through Qinsy file
for index_qinsy,row_qinsy in qinsy_file_2.iterrows():
    # Loop through SEGY navigation
    for index_segy,row_segy in segy_vlookup.iterrows():
        # Calculate distance between points
        if ((((segy_vlookup["CDP_X"][index_segy] - qinsy_file_2["CMP Easting"][index_qinsy])**2) + ((segy_vlookup["CDP_Y"][index_segy] - qinsy_file_2["CMP Northing"][index_qinsy])**2))**0.5)<= buffer:
            # Append rows less than the distance modifier to the new dataframe 
            out_df=pd.concat([out_df,row_qinsy])
            break
        else:
                pass
```

So far I have read through the following:

- [How to iterate over rows in a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe) (and others of a similar name)
- [Looking for faster way to iterate over pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422664/looking-for-faster-way-to-iterate-over-pandas-dataframe)
- [What is the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas)
- https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/how-iterate-over-rows-pandas/
- https://towardsdatascience.com/you-dont-always-have-to-loop-through-rows-in-pandas-22a970b347ac

Comment: "*I've spent the last dayreading up on how to make Pandas more efficient*" ; `qinsy_file_2.iterrows` -> not sure what you have read, but you should find a bit everywhere that you should **not** use `iterrows`…

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your data, an explanation of what you're doing and the matching expected output.

Comment: `out_df=pd.concat([out_df,row_qinsy])` is something you should never ever do. It iteratively create bigger and bigger dataframe resulting in a quadratic time (not to mention creating a dataframe has a huge overhead). You should accumulate data in one/multiple lists and then create a dataframe from that. I expect this to be a significant bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending from the *loop vectorization* domain you looked into, try keywords *pairwise distance calculation*, e.g.: [How to efficiently calculate euclidean distance matrix for several timeseries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62258519/12846804)

The method below is fully vectorized (no `for` loops at all). It passes by Numpy for the 2D intensive part, then returns a pandas dataframe as requested.
Calculating distances and filtering rows by *<= buffer*, with your input data sizes of 1500 * 15000 rows, is accomplished in a fraction of a second.

---

**Mock-up data**
Let

- `dfA` represent `qinsy_file_2` with `nA = 15000` points of 2D coordinates `('xA', 'yA')`
- `dfB` represent `segy_vlookup` with `nB = 1500` points of 2D coordinates `('xB', 'yB')`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

buffer = 0.01 # arbitrary value

dfA = pd.DataFrame({'xA' : np.random.default_rng(seed=0).random(nA), 
                    'yA' : np.random.default_rng(seed=1).random(nA)})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'xB' : np.random.default_rng(seed=3).random(nB), 
                    'yB' : np.random.default_rng(seed=4).random(nB)})
```

With these given seeds if you wanted to reproduce the process:

```
             xA        yA
0      0.636962  0.511822
1      0.269787  0.950464
2      0.040974  0.144160
3      0.016528  0.948649
4      0.813270  0.311831
...         ...       ...
14995  0.457170  0.507611
14996  0.283829  0.828005
14997  0.679110  0.910104
14998  0.273703  0.294932
14999  0.097813  0.366295

[15000 rows x 2 columns]

            xB        yB
0     0.085649  0.943056
1     0.236811  0.511328
2     0.801274  0.976244
3     0.582162  0.080836
4     0.094129  0.607356
...        ...       ...
1495  0.684086  0.821719
1496  0.383240  0.957020
1497  0.341389  0.064735
1498  0.032523  0.234434
1499  0.500383  0.931106

[1500 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

**One-liner summary**

```
df_out = dfA[np.sum((np.sqrt((np.atleast_2d(dfA['xA'].values) - 
                              np.atleast_2d(dfB['xB'].values).T) **2 +
                             (np.atleast_2d(dfA['yA'].values) - 
                              np.atleast_2d(dfB['yB'].values).T) **2))<=buffer, axis=0)>0]
```

---

**Detailed answer**

Each point from `dfA` will be tested for distance < *buffer* regarding each point from `dfB`, to determine if the corresponding row of `dfA` should be selected into `df_out`

**Distance matrix**
Every column in the output below stands for a row in `dfA`:

```
D = np.sqrt((np.atleast_2d(dfA['xA'].values) - 
             np.atleast_2d(dfB['xB'].values).T) **2 +
            (np.atleast_2d(dfA['yA'].values) - 
             np.atleast_2d(dfB['yB'].values).T) **2)
D
[[0.69993476 0.18428648 0.80014469 ... 0.59437473 0.67485498 0.57688898]
 [0.40015149 0.44037255 0.41613029 ... 0.59552573 0.21951799 0.20088488]
 [0.49263227 0.53211262 1.12712974 ... 0.13891991 0.86169468 0.93107222]
 ...
 [0.535957   0.88861864 0.3107378  ... 0.91033173 0.2399422  0.38764484]
 [0.66504838 0.75431549 0.0906694  ... 0.93520197 0.24865128 0.14713943]
 [0.44096846 0.23140718 0.91123077 ... 0.17995671 0.6753528  0.69359482]]
```

**Now filter by threshold** (distance < *buffer*)
At least *one* value per column in `D` is enough to select that column for `df_out`, i.e. that row in `dfA`.

```
b = np.sum(D<=buffer, axis=0)>0 # boolean selector
[ True False False ... False  True  True] # In this example, at least the first, 
# last and former last rows will be selected, and probably many more in between.
```

Finally operate row-wise selection on dfA:

```
df_out = dfA[b]
             xA        yA
0      0.636962  0.511822
4      0.813270  0.311831
9      0.935072  0.027559
10     0.815854  0.753513
11     0.002739  0.538143
...         ...       ...
14988  0.039833  0.239034
14994  0.243440  0.428287
14996  0.283829  0.828005
14998  0.273703  0.294932
14999  0.097813  0.366295

[5620 rows x 2 columns]
```

In this mock-up example, 5620 rows out of 150000 made it to the selection.
Naturally any additional columns that your actual `dfA` might have will also be transcribed into `df_out`.

To go further, but this answer already reprsents a dramatic improvement over nested loops, reduce number of distances actually calculated?

- Here no playing with symmetry to reduce calculations as in actual pairwise distance algorithms (that typically tries a dataset against itself). One has to calculate all products.
- I wonder, though, would it be advantageous to go by chunks, calculating the next chunk for that point only if condition was not already satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you could provide a minimal reproducible example with some example data.

My first thought would be to do a cross join using merge(how='cross'). With large amounts of data this is dangerous because it's a cartesian product. However, once you have your joined data, you can apply your calculation in a vectorised manner across the whole frame.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161978/pandas-two-dataframe-cross-join) for more details

Comment: Hi Adam - just working on the code to get the minimal reproducible example - apologies!